# How to access db data in a svf model?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm looking for a way to acces "property data" in a programmatic way in my svf model open in auto desk viewer.

https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers-dev/latest/docs/PropDbLoader.html

I found that in the api, but can figure out how it should be working and what data it needs.
The API documentation seems exhaustive but is not of any help on how to use those function...

I'm trying to make an extension, that when on click, i could access property of the model part that i clicked on.

( the same data that I can see in the property section of the basic viewer )

So far I have that:

```
MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.onSelectionEvent = function(event) {
//here i have an ID related to the part clicked
var currSelection = this.viewer.getSelection();

//here I acces what seems to be the data loader, which is defined
console.log(event.model.myData.propDbLoader );

//but here, when i give the first id, it respond null
event.model.myData.propDbLoader.getProperties( currSelection, (e)=>{
    console.log('success',e );
},(e) => {
    console.log('error',e );
} );
```

Any idea would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several APIs to query the model data through Viewer:
[Viewer.search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/model/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames):

```
viewer.search('keywords',dbids=>console.log(dbids),err=>console.error(err))
```

[Viewer.getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/model/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback)

```
Viewer.getProperties(dbId,rst=>console.log(rst),err=>console.error(err))
```

[Viewer.model.getBulkProperties](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers-dev/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Model.html):

```
Viewer.model.getBulkProperties(dbids,['propname1','prop2'],rst=>console.log(rst), err=>console.error(err))
```